# Why don't my characters operate on defense when village is attacked?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What level air balloons operate as defense in addition to offense? Is it level 6? Would this be true for all characters; like dragon or minion need to be up to level 6 for defense?

Comment: unless it changed since ive played last, the only thing that should change whether or not your troops defend or not is if your clan castle is set to sleep or not. If you have troops in your clan castle, and its not set to asleep, they should defend your base. Your army in your army camps wont defend though

Comment: ah shoot army camps never defend?

Comment: so do defense troops always have to come from a clan member donating them to you??

Comment: no, they are just for attacking. If you want Troops to defend, you will need a clan castle and to be in a clan. Then your clan can donate troops for you clan castle for defending

Comment: If they donate troops, are they there forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troops in your army camps are only for attacking, not defending. If you would like to have troops defend your base, you can repair your [clan castle](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Clan_Castle) and join a clan. Once you have both a clan castle and a clan, you can request troops from your clan to defend your base. These troops will continue to defend your base until they are killed by an attacker, or you use them for attacking.